# Validating an XML file against my custom schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to learn XML, and I have come up with a schema and sample file example to see if I know what I'm doing before I get to far.

.xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Assumption" type="assumptionType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="assumptionType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="entries" type="entriesType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="entriesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="entry">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                        <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assumption>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <x>12</x>
            <y>14</y>
            <value>16</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <x>12</x>
            <y>24</y>
            <value>5</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</Assumption>
```

I am using [this tool](http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/) to try to validate the .xml against the .xsd.  I am getting the following error:

```
The following errors were found: 
TYPE              LOC       MESSAGE 
Validation        9, 10     cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting
                            with element 'entry'. No child element is expected at this point
```

I'm obviously not understanding something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **`entry`** is multiple node, you need to specify **`maxOccurs="unbounded"`**

Your XSD would be:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Assumption" type="assumptionType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="assumptionType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="entries" type="entriesType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="entriesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                        <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```